# How to give some space to every page in printing only using css

Tags: html, css, printing

I want to give some space to top of every page which is applied in only in printing mode.
is it possible or not..?

I am using:

```
@page { margin-top : 30px; }
```

But it doesn't get applied..
Are there any other methods available in css..?

[image: This is my first page.. see top of the image.it has some space..]

[image: This is my second page.. see top of the image.it has no space..]

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, refer this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first also, it's not supported in firefox, refer nathan's answer instead

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following way.

```
@media print
  {
   body {margin-top:30px;}
  }
```

This will select and target only the print related CSS changes. Hope this helps.

**PS:* I have taken Body element, but if you want, you can target specific wrapper that is part of your HTML and you can target it specifically only if you want that wrapper to start from top with certain spacing. You have the solution with logic. Use it to match your scenarios.*

Comment: Voted, but it would be better to have a wrapper element and than use `margin-top: 30px;` on that wrapper, if this suffice the OP than well and good... :)

Comment: is it applied in every page..?
or only in first page..?

Comment: Agreed - @Mr.Alien, but the OP has mentioned to have space for top, so no specific mention has been there as to his code, so let him take the logic and if he needs for the wrapper, he can take the same code and put a wrapper. I shall mention the same on my answer. Thanks Aliey ;
)

Comment: Only on your master CSS stylesheet. No need to make it hard coded. - @mani

Comment: @NathanLee Thank you for reply. Here my problem i am trying to print report in my application.(The report is 10-15 pages). Presently in my first only getting some space on top of the page.. i need to get some top space in remaining page also.. how can i do that..?

Comment: Use the below `body{margin-top:40px; margin-bottom:40px;}` - @mani

Comment: @NathanLee i updated the post..
please check it once..
i need uniform top spacing in all pages..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45462/discussion-between-mani-and-nathan-lee)